# How can I use Frame.Navigate method in Windows Phone application?

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing application on Windows Phone 8.1 and I have problem with navigating to another page. Probably I can't use Frame.Navigate in proper way. I want to navigate to page for example InformationView (which is in Views folder). I did it like this:

Frame.Navigate(typeof(InformationView));

but I have error: Cannot convert from System.Type to System.Uri.
I'm new in Windows Phone and don't understand this problem. Anybody can help?

Comment: It is hard to help without the context of the line, could you had some more code?

Comment: Is your `InformationView` of type `Page`?

Comment: It's PhoneApplicationPage

Comment: `PhoneApplicationPage` means the project is a Windows Phone Silverlight project. The `Frame.Navigate` has different signatures in Windows Phone Silverlight and Windows Phone Runtime projects, WP Sliverlight accepts `System.Uri` while WP Runtime accepts `System.Type`. Be aware of this when looking for examples or documentation in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

As the error said, the `Frame.Navigate` expects `System.Uri` containing the relative path to the view you want to navigate, for example like this:

```
Frame.Navigate(new Uri("Views/InformationView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Ok, but now I have error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Frame.Navigate(Uri)"

Comment: In the `xaml` of the page of code behind which you're inserting this code, what is the value of  `Name` attribute of `Frame` tag?

Comment: I don't have a Frame tag, i can't even create it ("The type "Frame" was not found")

Comment: I tried use NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/InformationView.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); but then I have NullReferenceException